# how to get automate to use /usr/include/glib-2.0 instead of /usr/local/include/glib-2.0

Tags: build, makefile, glib

I am not sure when this change occurred on my system, but I used to be able to build something that used /usr/include/glib-2.0.  But now my build is failing due to glib, and I notice that it is using another version of /usr/local/include/glib-2.0.

How can I get it to use /usr/lib instead of /usr/local/lib for glib?  I tried removing /usr/local/include/glib-2.0 and /usr/local/lib/glib-2.0, but it still tries to use those paths and fails.

Answer (score 0):

well, a solution I found was to download the glib source, build it and install it to /usr/local, and then run "sudo make uninstall" ... kind of a hack, but it worked

Answer (score 0):

The best way of getting the proper path to glib in your buildscripts is to use the pkg-config tool to get the flags for gcc.
E.g
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0) foo.c

Answer (score 0):

If you have eveer compiled and installed glib by yourself and did not change the prefix, you might have `glib-2.0.pc` in pkg-config's default search path.  You can check which `.pc` file is used with `--debug` option.

Or, you can check the contents of `glib-2.0.pc` to see it has the right `prefix` or not.